# How to simplify a profile completion calculation that has multiple if statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a working code below to calculate profile completion percentage. Each field is assigned a weightage and if that field is passed, the weightage is added to the completion score. While this works, this can probably be done with shorter code?

```
export function profileProgress(user) {
  const name = 5;
  const dob = 15;
  const languages = 10;
  const profilePic = 15;
  const gender = 15;
  const educations = 5;
  const certifications = 10;
  ...
  ...
  let profileCompletion;
  if (user.name) {
    profileCompletion+=name;
  }
  if (user.dob) {
    profileCompletion+=dob;
  }
  if (user.languages) {
    profileCompletion+=languages;
  }
  ...
  ...
  return profileCompletion;
}
```

Comment: `let profileCompletion;` <-- undefined and you are adding numbers to undefined. You need to set it to `0`

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have an object indexed by `user` property, whose values are the associated weights for each property.

```
const weights = {
  name: 5,
  dob: 15,
  languages: 10,
  // ...
};
return Object.entries(weights)
  .reduce((a, [key, weight]) => a + (user[key] ? weight : 0), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the property names with [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) if you put them all in an object.

```
const weights = {
  name: 5,
  dob: 15,
  languages: 10,
  //...
};
let completion = 0;
for (let key in weights) {
  if (key in user) {
    completion += weights[key];
  }
}
```